# Construct object from multiples sources java 8 with custom function

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-8, java-stream

I have multiples sources (Maps) where i store data related to different attributes destined to contruct a final object with an id. These maps have different structures according this pattern :

Map

- id is the identifier of my final object FinalObject
- X1, X2 are attributes of my final object FinalObject

in real code i have several map as following :

```
Map<Integer, String> descriptions;
Map<Integer, Double> prices;
Map<Integer, Double> quantities;
Map<Integer, String> currencies;
```

I can merge the stream of my collections with `Stream.of()` but i have two issues to deal with, the structure of heterogenous maps and an also for each entry i want to create a Final object in a Java8 manner.

I think of my `MultipleFunction` as BiFunction my defined attributes for the FinalObject as arguments. Is it okay as a design ?

Any opionions or advises?

The result of the merging would be like this :

```
Stream.of(descriptions.entrySet(), prices.entrySet(), quantities.entrySet(), currencies.entrySet())
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> new FinalObject(description, price, quantity, currency)));
```

This code don't compile and is for my problem better comprehension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get a stream of the id numbers...

```
descriptions.keySet().stream()
```

...then look up the ids in the four maps:

```
descriptions.keySet().stream()
    .map(id -> {
         String description = descriptions.get(id);
         Double price       = prices      .get(id);
         Double quantity    = quantities  .get(id);
         String currency    = currencies  .get(id);

         return new FinalObject(description, price, quantity, currency);
    });
```

This assumes that `descriptions` has an entry for every single id. If not, adjust it as you see fit.

If you wish you could save one lookup by iterating over `entrySet()` instead of `keySet()`.

```
descriptions.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> {
         int id = e.getKey();

         String description = e.getValue();
         Double price       = prices    .get(id);
         Double quantity    = quantities.get(id);
         String currency    = currencies.get(id);

         return new FinalObject(description, price, quantity, currency);
    });
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I already know about map function but totally didn't consider to use it this obvious case. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose the `FinalObject` is immutable and has the following structure:

```
public static class FinalObject {

    private final String description;
    private final Double price;
    private final Double quantity;
    private final String currency;

    // constructor
```

Firstly create a set with all the ids from the maps. By the `Set` characteristics, the values are distinct:

```
final Set<Integer> idSet = new HashSet<>();
idSet.addAll(descriptions.keySet());
idSet.addAll(prices.keySet());
idSet.addAll(quantities.keySet());
idSet.addAll(currencies.keySet());
```

Then you can use the [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) in a quite neat and simple way to construct the objects:

```
final List<FinalObject> list = idSet.stream()
    .map(id -> new FinalObject(
            descriptions.get(id),
            prices.get(id),
            quantities.get(id),
            currencies.get(id)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```